# Empty server response from restful docker service

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I am unable to get a server response from my GO docker container. I tried sending a GET request using curl and I get the following response:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/weather/welcome
$ curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

.env

```
DATABASE_HOST=postgres_container
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE_NAME=weather
SERVER_PORT=8080
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  go_container:
    container_name: go_container
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - API_KEY=${API_KEY}
    build: .
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    depends_on:
      postgres_container:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure
    tty: true
    networks:
      - weather

  postgres_container:
    container_name: postgres_container 
    user: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql/create.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-U", "${DATABASE_USER}"]
    networks:
      - weather
volumes:
  db_data: {}
networks:
  weather:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.21.5

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /src

COPY .env .

COPY . .

RUN go mod download && go mod verify

RUN go build -o main cmd/app/main.go

ENTRYPOINT [ "./main" ]
```

server.go

```
package rest

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/randyVerduguez/randy-verduguez_06122023-BE-challenge/configs"
    "github.com/randyVerduguez/randy-verduguez_06122023-BE-challenge/http/rest/handlers"
    "github.com/randyVerduguez/randy-verduguez_06122023-BE-challenge/pkg/db"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type Server struct {
    logger *logrus.Logger
    router *mux.Router
    config configs.Config
}

func NewServer() (*Server, error) {
    config, err := configs.NewParsedConfig()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    database, err := db.Connect(db.ConfigDB{
        Host:     config.Database.Host,
        Port:     config.Database.Port,
        User:     config.Database.User,
        Password: config.Database.Password,
        Name:     config.Database.Name,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    log, err := NewLogger()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    handlers.Register(router, log, database)

    server := Server{
        logger: log,
        config: config,
        router: router,
    }

    return &server, nil
}

func (s *Server) Run(ctx context.Context) error {
    cors := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET"},
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
    })

    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    fmt.Sprintf(":%d", s.config.ServerPort),
        Handler: cors.Handler(s.router),
    }

    stopServer := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    signal.Notify(stopServer, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    defer signal.Stop(stopServer)

    serverErrors := make(chan error, 1)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()
        s.logger.Printf("REST API listening on  %d", s.config.ServerPort)
        serverErrors <- server.ListenAndServe()
    }(&wg)

    select {
    case err := <-serverErrors:
        return fmt.Errorf("error: starting REST API server %w", err)
    case <-stopServer:
        s.logger.Warn("server recieved STOP signal")

        err := server.Shutdown(ctx)

        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("graceful shutdown did not complete: %w", err)
        }

        wg.Wait()
        s.logger.Info("server was shutdown gracefully")
    }

    return nil
}

func (s *Server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    s.router.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

routes.go

```
package handlers

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func Register(r *mux.Router, lg *logrus.Logger, db *sqlx.DB) {
    handler := newHandler(lg, db)

    r.Use(handler.MiddlewareLogger())
    r.HandleFunc("/weather/current", handler.GetCurrentWeather()).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    r.HandleFunc("/weather/welcome", handler.Test()).Methods(http.MethodGet)
}
```

get.go

```
package handlers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "net/http"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "unicode"

    "github.com/randyVerduguez/randy-verduguez_06122023-BE-challenge/http/rest/types"
    "github.com/randyVerduguez/randy-verduguez_06122023-BE-challenge/pkg/erru"
)

func (s service) GetCurrentWeather() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var request types.Request

        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&request)

        if err != nil {
            s.respond(w, erru.ErrArgument{
                Wrapped: errors.New("Invalid request body"),
            }, http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        if request == (types.Request{}) {
            s.respond(w, erru.ErrArgument{
                Wrapped: errors.New("Invalid request body"),
            }, http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        params := reflect.ValueOf(request)

        for i := 0; i < params.NumField(); i++ {
            param := params.Field(i).String()
            if len(param) == 0 || !isAlpha(param) {
                s.respond(w, erru.ErrArgument{
                    Wrapped: errors.New("Invalid request body"),
                }, http.StatusBadRequest)
                return
            }
        }

        request.Name = strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(request.Name))
        request.Region = strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(request.Region))
        request.Country = strings.TrimSpace(strings.ToLower(request.Country))
        getResponse, err := s.toDoService.Get(r.Context(), request)

        if err != nil {
            s.respond(w, err, http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        s.respond(w, types.Response{
            Name:       getResponse.Name,
            Region:     getResponse.Region,
            Country:    getResponse.Country,
            TempC:      getResponse.TempC,
            TempF:      getResponse.TempF,
            FeelsLikeC: getResponse.FeelsLikeC,
            FeelsLikeF: getResponse.FeelsLikeF,
            WindMph:    getResponse.WindMph,
            WindKph:    getResponse.WindKph,
            Humidity:   getResponse.Humidity,
            CreatedOn:  getResponse.CreatedOn,
        }, http.StatusOK)
    }
}

func (s service) Test() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        s.respond(w, "Welcome :)", http.StatusOK)
    }
}

func isAlpha(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if unicode.IsSpace(c) {
            continue
        }

        if !unicode.IsLetter(c) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Seems like it might be a conflict with the ports I am exposing. FYI: all services are running well w/o errors by the looks of it.

Comment: I only see a CORS handler in your code.  I don't see any GET handler.

Comment: Alright, I added the GET handlers and routes to OP.

Comment: Are you sure `s.config.ServerPort` is set to `8080`? You can also try sending the request within the container to check if the issue is with the server itself or with the container setup. You can do this with `docker-compose exec go_container curl localhost:8080/weather/welcome` (if curl is installed within the container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to bind my go app to the addresss 0.0.0.0 like so

```
services:
  go_container:
    container_name: go_container
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - API_KEY=${API_KEY}
    build: .
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    command: go run cmd/app/main.go -b 0.0.0.0
    depends_on:
      postgres_container:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure
    tty: true
    networks:
      - weather

  postgres_container:
    container_name: postgres_container 
    user: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql/create.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-U", "${DATABASE_USER}"]
    networks:
      - weather
volumes:
  db_data: {}
networks:
  weather:
    driver: bridge
```